# UITabbar Badge value from MySQL

Tags: mysql, swift

I have an iPhone app with a PHP and MySQL backend.  I have a tab bar at the bottom and want to display a badge showing the number of user messages stored in the database.

I've tested the PHP file and MySQL query and they both work.  I've also hard coded the badge number to see if the Swift code works as well and it does.  Where I'm stuck is when I bring all three together the **value still doesn't show on the tab bar**.  I printed the value and it's indeed there just not on the tab.

Here is the code:

```
// func of loading posts from server
func loadPosts()->[String] {

     // append all posts var's inf to tweets
     self.hhmessages = messages as! [AnyObject]
     //print(self.hhmessages)

      self.incoming = []

      // getting images from url paths
      for i in 0 ..< self.hhmessages.count {

       // path we are getting from $returnArray that assigned to parseJSON > to posts > tweets
          let incoming = self.hhmessages[i]["badgecount"]!
          print(incoming! as Any)

          // Access the elements (NSArray of UITabBarItem) (tabs) of the tab Bar
          let tabItems = self.tabBar.items as NSArray?

          // In this case we want to modify the badge number of the third tab:
          let tabItem = tabItems![3] as! UITabBarItem
          let messagevalue = incoming!

          print(messagevalue as Any)

          // Now set the badge of the third tab
          tabItem.badgeValue = messagevalue as? String
      }
      // reload tableView to show back information          
   }
```

Comment: Can you post the log of print statement from above code?

Comment: It's just the number 1 in the log, which is the number of new messages.

Comment: I suspect because of loop the number is somehow becoming 0 and thus resetting the badge. Print and see the value after existing loop

Comment: okay you're right it's printing [ ] when I print outside the loop.  Should I get rid of the loop? I know I will only have one row returning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay so try using the following structure.

```
func loadPosts() {

    //1. instead of -> self.hhmessages = messages as! [AnyObject]
    self.hhmessages = messages as! [[String: Any]]  //the hhmessages shoud be of type [[String: Any]] better readabilty

    //2. self.incomin = []  -> What is this used for?

    //3. we will create new variable to store all the badge counts for future refrence
    var badgeCount = 0

    //4. loop through the messages and get the badge count (Not sure if badgeCount is the key or unread)
    //but I'll go as you have done
    for message in hhmessages {
        if let count = message["badgecount"] as? Int {
            badgeCount += count
        }
    }

    //5. we have the badge count so we will access the tabbar to which we will display the badge icon
    if let tabItems = self.tabBar.items {
        let thirdTab = tabItems[2] //get the third tab item

        //6. set the value of badge
        thirdTab.badgeValue = "\(badgeCount)"

    }
}
```

Comment: Happy to help :)